# React.js HashRouter 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash, react-router

I have a problem with implementing fully functional `404` page with React `HashRouter`.

`routes.tsx`

```
export const Routes = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
      <Route path="/route1" component={Route1} />
      <Route path="/route2" component={Route2} />
      <Route component={ErrorPage} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
);
```

`app.tsx`

```
<>
  ...
  <Routes />
  ...
</>
```

Current behaviour:

1. When typing in address bar `{url}/#/{non-existing-route}`, then behaviour is correct - browser displays `ErrorPage`
2. When typing in address bar `{url}/{non-existing-route}`, then behaviour is incorrect - browser changes url to `{url}/{non-existing-route}#/` and displays `Home` page.

I would like `ErrorPage` to be displayed in both situations.

This problem does not occur when I am using `BrowserRouter`, but I must use `HashRouter` here.

Thanks for your help in advance!